AWS Lambda call is not logging in console
I am learning Lambda and trying to migrate my local app to a AWS lambda.
It is very simple. Just a function which calls a external service.
My handler method call this method:
export const addTrack = async (token: string, parameters: any) => {
    const url: string = process.env.URL as string
    const headers = { ...globalHeaders, "authorization": "Bearer " + token };
    try {
        console.log("PARAMS:", parameters);
        let response = await axios.put(url, parameters, { headers })        
        console.log('RESPONSE:', response.status + " | " + response.statusText + " | " + parameters.date + " | " + parameters.hours + " | " + parameters.comments)
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error trying to send a record:', parameters)
        console.error(e)
        throw new Error('Failing to call API: ' + e)
    }
}

handler method:
import { addTrack } from "./time-tracker-api-client"
import { DynamoDBClient, GetItemCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb"

const dynamoClient = new DynamoDBClient({})

export const handler = async (message: any) => {    
    let body = JSON.parse(message.Records[0].body);    

    let { Item }:any = await //call to dynamoBD...
    let token:string = Item.bdToken.S
    addTrack(token, body)
}

Note the console.log before and after axios.put call and a log in the catch block. I am having some intermitent logs here. Sometimes it shows, sometimes not.
The log with PARAMS always shows, so it is correct. But sometimes the RESPONSE log does not show in cloudwatch logs in any streams, but also does not show any error log.
It seems the put call is causing some error, but it do not enter in the catch block. The weird thing is sometimes when error happens in tha put call, it shows in the log.
For example, lambda is called 20 times, I have 20 PARAMS log in streams, My external services respond to 17 calls. I have only 17 RESPONSE logs and 1 errors logs. Seems 2 error logs is missing. Sometimes the external call works, but the RESPONSE log does not appear
I do not understand what is happening here. Can someone have some tips in what is happening?
I have tried to call using the .then().catch() in put call, but it does not work also.

This might have been caused because the log level by default is ERROR and it will drop any other level of logs. You can try to set a log level to INFO and retry.

Also as a side note, I'd recommend you use logging libraries instead of console.log. You can try Pino, Bunyan, Winston etc.

@ParmanM.Alizadeh but INFO and ERROR logs are showing. Eventually, they are lost

Can you share more information about the other code that invokes this addTrack function? Do you have any other global variables that require instantiation outside of your handler function? Can you share your function definition IaC if you have any (SAM, Terraform, CDK)?

@M.Brandao When are they lost? Right after the lambda execution finishes? Or sometime after that? Have you checked your log stream retention period configuration?

@AllanChua I added the handler code.

@ParmanM.Alizadeh maybe is sometimes after that. The log retention is OK.
I am thinking here if it is possible to be because of asynchronous call od addTrack method. The handler is calling addTrack in async. Then lambda finishes before the log is placed in the stream. Is it possible?

@M.Brandao Not really, I suspect that's a possible scenario. Would you consider trying a logging library like Pino instead of Console.log?

Your addTrack function is async yet you don't await it or return its result.

I guess the problem is because of the async call on the method addTrack in the handler. I just added an await on this call and it started to log everything. When the call is async, I believe the lambda function finishes before the addTrack method has a chance to write the log.

It seems that you are getting spontaneous errors (3 out of 20) because your Lambda function's code handler is not awaiting the addTrack function to complete before terminating. To ensure that addTrack function is completely executing, change your handler code to the following:
import { addTrack } from "./time-tracker-api-client"
import { DynamoDBClient, GetItemCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb"

const dynamoClient = new DynamoDBClient({})

export const handler = async (message: any) => {    
    let body = JSON.parse(message.Records[0].body);    

    let { Item }:any = await //call to dynamoBD...
    let token:string = Item.bdToken.S

    // Gracefully await the addTrack function to finish.
    await addTrack(token, body);
}


Yes. That is exactly what is happening. Probably lambda finishes its instance before the method addTrack finishes the execution. This explains also why generally the last records are not called in the external api.
